# Object serialization and deserialization when class field changed

Tags: java

I have a question about Object serialization and deserialization when class field changed.

If an object with type MyClass

```
MyClass {
    String str1;
    LinkedList mylist = new LinkedList();
    String str2;
```

}

has been serialized to file.

Then I changed the code which changes MyClass definition to

```
MyClass {
    String str1;
    LinkedList mylist = new LinkedList();
    Map myMap = new HashMap();
```

}

After that, I deserialize the object from file to a MyClass object using the changed code. Is it OK? Will there any exception thrown during deserialization? I want to reuse the old object. I.e. I want the de-serializing can be done. So I hope there is no exception thrown.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Managing serveral versions of serialized Java objects.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678136/managing-serveral-versions-of-serialized-java-objects)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, on the contrary, you'll run into great problems. In Joshua Bloch's [Effective Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321356683), Item 74, he notes to implement Serializable judiciously, as it decreases the flexibility to change a class's implementation once its been released.

He specifically notes that "If you do not make the effort to design a custom serializable form, but merely accept the default, the serialized form will be forever tied to the class's original internal representation."

Answer (score 2):

This is why you should have a serialVersionUID. It would  be different between the two versions, and your code would know it can't be done, and stop the de-serializing.

Comment: I want to reuse the old object. I.e. I want the de-serializing can be done. That's the reason I will use the same serialVersionUID.

Comment: It will blow up. You can keep the old version of the class, and make a new version with a new name... then have the new version use a constructor to map values from old class to new class...

Answer (score 2):

If you remove fields from an object, then older objects will not deserialize.  THe way to do this is to always use the same serialVersionUID and never remove fields, only add them.