# Java de-serialization backward compatibility

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization

How can I deserialize a class which was modified after serialization?

More specifically, I know this can be done when a class had `serialVersionUID` in its initial version. Is there any way to do it for classes without `serialVersionUID`?

I have an object

```
package com.test.serialize;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class MyObject implements Serializable{

    String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

and I serialize classes like this

```
package com.test.serialize;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;

public class SerializeTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            MyObject myObject = new MyObject();
            myObject.setName("Ajit");

            ObjectOutputStream objectOStr = null;
            ByteArrayOutputStream byteOStr = null;
            try {
                byteOStr = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                objectOStr = new ObjectOutputStream(byteOStr);
                objectOStr.writeObject(myObject);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (objectOStr != null)
                        objectOStr.close();
                } catch (IOException e2) {
                }
            }
            FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(new File("serialize"));
            fo.write(byteOStr.toByteArray());
            fo.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

and deserialize like this

```
package com.test.serialize;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;

public class DeserializeTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {

    //          File f = new File("serialize");
    //          FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(f);
            RandomAccessFile raF = new RandomAccessFile("serialize", "r");
            byte[] b = new byte[(int)raF.length()];
            raF.read(b);

            ObjectInputStream oIstream = null;
            ByteArrayInputStream bIstream = null;

            bIstream = new ByteArrayInputStream(b);
            oIstream = new ObjectInputStream(bIstream);
            Object finalResult = oIstream.readObject();
            System.out.println(finalResult.toString());
        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

After some time, I added

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "MyObject [name=" + name + ", names=" + names + "]";
}
```

to `MyObject`. After adding that I got exceptions like

```
java.io.InvalidClassException: com.test.serialize.MyObject; local class in 
compatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 5512234731442983181, local class
serialVersionUID = -6186454222601982895
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:617)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1622)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1517)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1771)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
at com.test.serialize.DeserializeTest.main(DeserializeTest.java:25)
```

Please help me with this.

Comment: You should set the new version's `serialVerionUID` to the one you see for the old version and use the appropriate `readObject`/`writeObject` methods.

Comment: If you enable all compiler warnings, and pay attention to them, the compiler will tell you that this is going to happen because you didn't supply a serialVersionUID field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @Gábor Bakos.

This can be solved by creating  serialVersionUID for older class (Which signatures should be same as the one during serialization )and adding that serialVersionUID in current class.

```
serialver -classpath /***PATH***/bin com.test.serialize.MyObject
```

That returns

```
com.test.serialize.MyObject:    static final long serialVersionUID = 5512234731442983181L;
```

After that I have added it to my MyObject as below

```
package com.test.serialize;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class MyObject implements Serializable{

    /**
     * Added serial version Id of old class, created before adding new fields
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5512234731442983181L;


public MyObject() {
    System.out.println("Constructor");
}

String name;


public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}


String names ="Altered after change!";

public String getNames() {
    return names;
}

public void setNames(String names) {
    System.out.println("Setting names");
    this.names = names;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "MyObject [name=" + name + ", names=" + names + "]";
}

}
```

It works fine.

More info refer: [serialver](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/serialver.html)

Answer (score 0):

First advice: use serialization, because everything is almost done.

Second advice: use a serialVersionUID and keep it fix with one version: it is here to warn you and prevent confusion between different serialized versions.

So : if you change fields or meaning of fields, change the serialVersionUID.

Then you have your backward compatibility problem.

See this for many ideas: [Managing several versions of serialized Java objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678136/managing-several-versions-of-serialized-java-objects)

IMHO:

- whatever solution you take, keep in mind that your program will be managing objects with partial datas: then you have to manage all cases with or without datas.
- if you dont change often your version: use several different classes. Perhaps subclasses, or implementations of an interface: then you can get your program, and you manage several versions of object: MyClass_V1, MyClass_V2, etc. When you deserialize, you can test/retry and get the good Object. After that, you perhaps have to convert datas between your classes
- if you change your version, by adding new fields (not changing old fields), it is a little more easy (subclasses, converting is direct to parents)
- or you could consider use a XML structure to serialize and deserialize: you can have backward and forward compatibility because it is **extensible**: fields are there, or are null. You have to manage mapping yourself or use some libraries.

Hope it helps !

Comment: Changing serialVersionUID with every new class version is an urban myth put about by people who evidently have never actually done it. If you really did that you would instantly have an inoperable system. The idea s neevr to change it at all, and to manage th changes to the class such that they stay within the bounds specified in the Versioning chapter f the Object Serialization Specification.

Comment: javadoc is also some sort of urban myth : "a serialVersionUID, which is used during deserialization to verify that the sender and receiver of a serialized object have loaded classes for that object that are compatible with respect to serialization." then compatibiliy = you can keep the version number. incompatibility = change it. With that, version management is robust as wanted. Other magical tricky self-minded-management is certainly interesting, but I dont understand the benefits of re-inventing this wheel and am not sure of its continuity ...

Answer (score -1):

I would remember following points,

1. Every `Serializable` class contains a `serialVersionUID` ( it doesn't matter if you have specified the one explicitly or not ).
2. There are compatible changes and there are incompatible changes
   e.g. adding a new field is a compatible change, removing a field is not a compatible change. Adding / removing / editing a method are generally compatible changes but in your case surely that is not the way it is ( `serialVersionUID` got changed after you added `toString()` method)

3.Prior to modify the class, you can use **serialver** utility to find `serialVersionUID` of old class and use that in new class

Don't think there are any other magic tricks :)

Comment: Removing a field does not prevent the class from being deserialized. The object is correctly read in but any fields that exist in the stream but not in the class are essentially discarded. Any fields that exist in the class but not in the stream are set to default values (null/0).