# GlassFish - IllegalStateException

Tags: java, oracle, jpa, jboss, glassfish

I'm making a small application. For now it has a couple of entity classes and a `index.xhtml` which just has the word `TEST`. It seems that when I try to run it on the server, the application doesn't create a database and the glassfish server gives me the error :

```
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.IllegalStateException: WELD-000227: Bean identifier index inconsistency detected - the distributed container probably does not work with identical applications
Expected hash: 1888662881
Current index: BeanIdentifierIndex [hash=-1322634367, indexed=12]:
0: WELD%AbstractBuiltInBean%WebProjectManager%HttpSession
1: WELD%AbstractBuiltInBean%com.ibm.jbatch.container.cdi.BatchCDIInjectionExtension%HttpSession
2: WELD%AbstractBuiltInBean%com.sun.faces.flow.FlowDiscoveryCDIExtension%HttpSession
3: WELD%AbstractBuiltInBean%org.glassfish.cdi.transaction.TransactionalExtension%HttpSession
4: WELD%AbstractBuiltInBean%org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi1x.internal.CdiComponentProvider%HttpSession
5: WELD%AbstractBuiltInBean%org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi1x.servlet.internal.CdiExternalRequestScopeExtension%HttpSession
6: WELD%AbstractBuiltInBean%org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi1x.transaction.internal.TransactionalExceptionInterceptorProvider%HttpSession
7: WELD%AbstractBuiltInBean%org.glassfish.jms.injection.JMSCDIExtension%HttpSession
8: WELD%AbstractBuiltInBean%org.glassfish.osgicdi.impl.OSGiServiceExtension%HttpSession
9: WELD%AbstractBuiltInBean%org.glassfish.sse.impl.ServerSentEventCdiExtension%HttpSession
10: WELD%AbstractBuiltInBean%org.hibernate.validator.internal.cdi.ValidationExtension%HttpSession
11: WELD%AbstractBuiltInBean%root_WebProjectManager%HttpSession
```

**persistence.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence     http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
version="2.0">
<persistence-unit name="WebProjectManager">
<provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
 <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
<properties>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>

  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="alexander"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="0898725863"/>

  <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-or-extend-tables"/>
  <property name="eclipselink.create-ddl-jdbc-file-name" value="createDDL_ddlGeneration.jdbc"/>
  <property name="eclipselink.drop-ddl-jdbc-file-name" value="dropDDL_ddlGeneration.jdbc"/>
  <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode" value="both"/>
</properties>
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Any ideas how to fix this ?

**PS:** I only have entity classes at this point so maybe that's the reason it doesn't create the database (maybe it needs, some ejb's and managed beans for example. Note sure.). Don't really know so here is the whole project so far: [project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-LAX_pu8QCUdDg3VXNBUDNKTU0/view)

Comment: And how the error you provided points to the DB creation issue?

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28713747/4308751) question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a [WELD bug](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WELD-1887).

Work around the issue by disabling session passivation on shutdown in Tomcat or GlassFish.

Answer (score 0):

Just restart Server:

- GlasFish Server
- Apache Tomcat

whatever you are using

On Netbeans click -> Services -> Servers-> Right-click(mouse) any server and **restart**

Answer (score -1):

I think you must add

```
transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL"
```

or

```
transaction-type="JTA"
```

in

```
<persistence-unit name="WebProjectManager" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
```