# org.jboss.weld.exceptions.IllegalStateException: WELD-000227 after every change in code

Tags: jakarta-ee, cdi, weld

I'm developing a webapp with NetBeans and Glassfish 4.1.1. and I'm using JSF and CDI to manage the backing beans for the facelets. Since shortly after changing anything in the code I always get an Internal Server Error with this IllegalStateException after 'successful' deploying and running the app via the browser:

```
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.IllegalStateException: WELD-000227: Bean 

identifier index inconsistency detected - the distributed container 

probably does not work with identical applications
```

I can get rid of it by doing a clean & build and redeploying. But NetBeans is redeploying automatically after every save anyway. So I then still have to click on clean and build and then on redeploy myself ALWAYS after any little change, it makes me crazy!

So is there any setting I can change on glassfish server to avoid this, or can I tell NetBeans to clean & build before autodeploy?

It was not always like this, recently I updated glassfish it may be that it appeared only after that, I don't remember exactly anymore.

Thanks in advance! It costs me so much time..

**SOLVED**

I googled again for hours and found the solution: I set a new system property in glassfish

org.jboss.weld.serialization.beanIdentifierIndexOptimization = **false**

to avoid the appearing inconsistencies as explained in the WELD reference here:

https://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/configure.html#_bean_identifier_index_optimization

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/28713747

Comment: How did you set this property? I'm struggling with the same issue.

Comment: in the admin console of glassfish (http://localhost:4848/) go to "server (Admin server)" --> "Properties" --> "System Properties" and add a new property "org.jboss.weld.serialization.beanIdentifierIndexOptimization" with value "false"

Comment: It worked for Websphere application server 9 also. Thanks.

Answer (score 17):

Disable beanIdentifierIndexOptimization in GlassFish as follows:

1. Visit the admin console at http://localhost:4848 (or https://127.0.0.1:4848/).
2. Click **Configurations**.
3. Click **server-config**.
4. Click **System Properties**.
5. Click **Add Property**.
6. Set **Instance Variable Name** to: `org.jboss.weld.serialization.beanIdentifierIndexOptimization`
7. Set **Default Value** to: `false`
8. Click **Save**.

This should help with passivation and resolve the following [WELD bug](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WELD-1887):

> WELD-000227: Bean identifier index inconsistency detected.

Comment: pull request for double up voting :)