# Java generics change on class field and serialization

Tags: java, serialization

I have a Java serialization question that is neither reported nor negated as problematic in Java Docs (for [JDK8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/serialization/spec/version.html#a6678)).

So, suppose I have a class that implements `Serializable`

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private List<CharSequence> values;
```

If I change `values` to

```
private List<String> values;
```

should I change the `serialVersionUID`?

Comment: Somebody might have serialized an instance with non-String instances in the list. So, yes. Why would this need to be mentioned in documentation explicitly?

Comment: Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284979/when-do-i-have-to-change-the-serialversionuid somewhat duplicate

Comment: @QingfeiYuan I disagree. The answer points to the same docs from Oracle that I mentioned. Nothing is said for what concern changes for generics.

Comment: @AndyTurner yeah, I see the point. So, at runtime deserialization will fail miserably. What about the opposite? So, if I change from `List<String>` to `List<CharSequence>` that is a supertype? It should work right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way to think of this serialization/deserialization operation is that it's a bit like casting.

Can you cast a `List<CharSequence>` to a `List<String>`? Not directly: the compiler will stop you, because generics are invariant. You can force it, however:

```
List<String> list = (List<String>) (List<?>) listOfCharSequences;
String entry = list.get(0);
```

and this *might* work a lot of the time, because, `String` is the most common `CharSequence`.

But it's possible that there's something else in there which is a `CharSequence`, but not a `String`, for example a `StringBuilder`. The code above would crash with a `ClassCastException`.

So, if you can be sure that all of your `CharSequence`s are genuinely `String`s, it's safe to make this change. Otherwise, you should either guard against it by changing the serial version id; or, in the case of `String`, you could simply invoke `toString()` on all of the elements:

```
List<String> listOfStrings = listOfCharSequences.stream()
    .map(cs -> Objects.toString(cs, null))
    .collect(toList())
```

(`String.toString()` returns itself, so this would return no new instance for elements that are already `String`s)

Comment: I agree, thanks for clarifying. Do you think that the opposite would work instead? So, changing a field from a type to its supertype?

Comment: @JeanValjean it depends if something running the old version of the code will ever read an instance written by the new version of the code. It's basically the same situation as the original question: if anything expecting a String reads something else, it will break.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make an incompatible change you should change the `serialVersionUID` so the you get an appropriate (if not nice) error instead of, say, a `ClassCastException` at some point further on.

If you want to maintain compatibility, keep the `serialVersionUID` and add a custom `readObject` method to convert the `List<CharSequence>` to `List<String>`.

**Edit:** To expand on that, if you want compatibility, your code should look something like this:

```
// final - for one thing I don't want to implement readObjectNoData
public final class JeanObject {
```

If this class was added as a subclass to another class then there would be "no data" in legacy serialised streams.

```
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    // Mutable field for Java Serialization, but treat as final.
    private List<String> values = new ArrayList<>();
```

If you want `values` to be `final` you will need a degenerate *Serialisation Proxy* hack where the proxy object is of the same type.

I am going to assume you want the collection object to be mutable. You probably shouldn't serialise mutable objects, but that's how it's usually used and how the OP's example feels.

```
    private void readObject(
        ObjectInputStream in
    ) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        ObjectInputStream.GetField fields = in.readFields();
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        var oldValues = (List<CharSequence>)fields.get("values", null);
        // Don't bother with nice error message.
        //   NPE if missing or null elements.
        this.values = oldValues.stream().collect(
            ArrayList::new,
            (values, value) -> values.add(value.toString()),
            List::addAll
        );
    }
    // ...
```

An alternative to the (very *functional-looking*) 3-arg `Stream.collect` is to use `Collectors.mapping`. An old-fashioned posh for loop would be less confusing all round, but that's not showing off on the internet - you'd look like someone who just gets stuff done.

`Collectors.toList` is probably not suitable as, say, adding an elements to the list someway down the line may result in an error. Maybe not today. Maybe not tomorrow. But when your successor's automatic updates the implementation. And they will hate you for the rest of their life. Here's the API docs talking:

> There are no guarantees on the type, mutability, serializability, or
>   thread-safety of the `List` returned

***Who wants that?***

**Edit:** Reading that quote again, you might not be able to serialise your deserialised object if you use `toList`...

(Code compiles but, as ever, is untested.)

Answer (score -2):

It is completely up to you. When you are specifying a serialVersionUID you are taking over the responsibility to change it when needed. 
If your system is in risk of encountering various versions of this object when you need to change  it.